# There is no network in the Performance tab of Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome

[my](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij740.jpg)

Where can I check it? A problem occurred during the lesson about page loading.

In the online lecture, network was in the performance tab.

I looked for the settings in Google Developer Tools and couldn't find it. help.